# Error: Expected [object Object] to be a GraphQL type

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

This code was working until I added the Resources part into the code. It is similar to the other two so I am not sure why isn't it working.

Thanks in advance

Update:-
After using the debugger, I came to understand that the problem is in the RootQueryType.js and files associated with it as the error pops up when I am trying to export the schema and exactly at the query:RootQueryType place but still can't pinpoint at the error.

Update:-
I have put the schema.js file too in the end

resourceType.js

```
const graphql = require("graphql");
const UserType = require("./userType");
const User = require("../models/User");
const Project = require("../models/Project");
const Resource = require("../models/Resource");
const ProjectType = require("./projectType");

const {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLList,
  } = graphql;


  const ResourceType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "ResourceType",
    fields: () => ({
      id: { type: GraphQLString },
      title: { type: GraphQLString },
      url: { type: GraphQLString },
      project:{
        type:ProjectType,
        resolve(parentValues,args){
          return Project.findById(parentValues.id).populate("resources")
        }
      }
    })
  });

  module.exports=ResourceType;
```

RootQueryType.js

```
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const graphql = require('graphql');
const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLList, GraphQLID, GraphQLNonNull } = graphql;

const ProjectType  = require('./../types/projectType');
const UserType  = require('./../types/userType');
const Project=require("../models/Project");
const User=require("../models/User");

 const RootQuery=new GraphQLObjectType({
    name:"RootQueryType",
    fields: () => ({
        projects:{
            type:new GraphQLList(ProjectType),
            resolve(parentValues,args,request){
                return Project.find().populate("contributors").populate("resources");
            }
        },
        project:{
            type:ProjectType,
            args:{id:{type:new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)}},
            resolve(parentValue,args,request){
                return Project.findById(args.id).populate("contributors").populate("resources");
            }
        },
        users:{
            type:new GraphQLList(UserType),
            resolve(parentValues,args,request){
                return User.find().populate("projects");
            }
        },
        user:{
            type:UserType,
            args:{id:{type:new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)}},
            resolve(parentValue,args,request){
                return User.findById(args.id).populate("projects")
            }
        },

    })
})

module.exports = RootQuery;
```

Mutation.js

```
    const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const ProjectType = require("./../types/projectType");
const UserType = require("./../types/userType");
const graphql = require("graphql");
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLNonNull,
  GraphQLString
} = graphql;

const Project = require("../models/Project");
const User = require("../models/User");

const mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "mutation",
  fields: () => ({
    addUser: {
      type: UserType,
      args: {
        name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
        username: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
        password: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
        email: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
        githubProfile: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) }
      },
      resolve(parentValues, args, request) {
        return User.create(args);
      }
    },
    addProject: {
      type: ProjectType,
      args: {
        name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
        description: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
        image: { type:GraphQLString },
        // contributor:{ type: new GraphQLNonNull(new GraphQLList(GraphQLID))
        contributor:{ type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
         },
      },
      resolve(parentValues, args, request) {
        return Project.create(args);
      }
    }
  })
});

module.exports = mutation;
```

I am positive it isnt the problem with other types because they were working earlier and I only added the .populate("resources") property to the resolve function of both of them. But just in case I am adding the code for them too.

userType.js

```
const graphql = require("graphql");
const ProjectType = require("./projectType");

const { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLString, GraphQLList } = graphql;

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "User",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    githubProfile: { type: GraphQLString },
    username: { type: GraphQLString },
    password: { type: GraphQLString },
    email: { type: GraphQLString },
    projects: {
      type: new GraphQLList(ProjectType),
      resolve(parentValues, args) {
        return User.findById(parentValues.id).populate("projects");
      }
    }
  })
});

module.exports = UserType;
```

and the other is

projectType.js

```
const graphql = require("graphql");
const UserType = require("./userType");
const ResourceType = require("./resourceType");
const User = require("../models/User");
const Project = require("../models/Project");

const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLList,
} = graphql;

const ProjectType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "ProjectType",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    description: { type: GraphQLString },
    image: { type: GraphQLString },
    contributors: {
      type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
      resolve(parentValues, args, request) {
        return Project.findContributors(parentValues.id);
      }
    },
    resources:{
      type: new GraphQLList(ResourceType),
      resolve(parentValues, args, request) {
        return Project.findResources(parentValues.id);
      }
    }
  })
});

module.exports=ProjectType;
```

schema.js

```
const graphql = require("graphql");
const RootQuery = require("./RootQueryType");
const Mutation = require("./Mutation");

const { GraphQLSchema } = graphql;

console.log(RootQuery,Mutation);

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: RootQuery,
  mutation: Mutation
});
```

Update:- I have removed the resources files and I am still getting the same error so it must be between user and project types

Update:-I finally tracked down the bug to being in the type files of both project and user type and it is being caused by the new GraphQLList, I still havent solved the error but removing it seems to make the error go away, no idea why.

Comment: What does the code look like that actually builds the `GraphQLSchema` object?

Comment: @Mord Zuber I have put the schema.js code in the end.

Comment: I wonder if `name: "RootQueryType",` needs to be `name: "query",`? 

Comment: Actually the whole thing was working before I added the resources.js part and integrate it so I don't think that is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the cyclic dependency between the `userType` and `projectType` module. Therefore the const value is still an empty object when it is passed to `GraphQLList`.

As a solution, you can move all the types into one module. Or, when exporting your classes, set them as properties of `module.exports`. This will work since you defined the fields properly as thunks.

By the way, you don't need the `new` when creating a `GraphQLList` or `GraphQLNonNull` wrapper. But that's not why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 6):

Finally solved the problem, it was as @cito said, because of circular dependencies that was the cause of the error, that is as my UserType is dependent on ProjectType and likewise and hence I was getting this error, this was solved by

```
const graphql = require("graphql");

const User = require("../models/User");
const Project = require("../models/Project");

const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLList,
} = graphql;

const ProjectType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "ProjectType",
  fields: () => ({
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
    description: { type: GraphQLString },
    image: { type: GraphQLString },
    contributors: {
      type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
      resolve(parentValues, args, request) {
        return Project.findContributors(parentValues.id);
      }
    },
    resources:{
      type: new GraphQLList(ResourceType),
      resolve(parentValues, args, request) {
        return Project.findResources(parentValues.id);
      }
    }
  })
});

module.exports=ProjectType;



// This is here to prevent circular dependencies problem which will lead to the formation of infinite loop

const UserType = require("./userType");
const ResourceType = require("./resourceType");
```

that is requiring the files at the bottom

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go is:

```
resources:{
      // require directly without creating a new variable
      type: new GraphQLList(require("./resourceType")),

      resolve(parentValues, args, request) {
        return Project.findResources(parentValues.id);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Just have both objectType in the same file.

I works